Should the accepted answer have all the info?
I posted a question somewhat recently (start of the month) that currently has two answers. Neither answer has all the info, and both answer posters know that.
I'm hesitant to accept either, as neither has all the info, and I don't want to just pick one answer and edit in the relevant data from the other, because then one answer will be incomplete and no longer useful, and might as well be deleted (and then the poster of that answer would lose 60 rep).
What should I do in this situation?

What should I do when someone answers my question?, What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?

Short Answer:
No
Long Answer:
For questions that ask how to do something, where to find something, et cetera, and have multiple valid answers, an accepted answer doesn't need to include every valid possibility, though including multiple of them is nice.
Let's explore an example here. Say, for instance, you are playing Builder Scrolls XVII Sun City (or some other hypothetical game), and you are wondering how to beat the first boss, a monstrously difficult opponent with 17 phases in which they heal to full and grow stronger each phase, and you ask a question here for help. In response, two eager people respond with answers. The first (possibly a Dark Souls enjoyer) gives you a detailed guide that walks you step by step through each phase of the fight, explaining exactly how to beat the boss, exactly as the developers intended you to. The second person (possibly a Dark Souls speed runner) gives you a very simple answer of standing near the edge of the platform, dodge rolling out of the way of the boss' charge attack, and power attacking them in the back to knock them off the platform and ending the fight in the first phase.
You (possibly a tea drinking, British exploiter), care not for what the developers intended for the fight and accept the second answer because you both value your time and your sanity and don't want to fight a 17 phase boss. While the second answer doesn't explain all of the stuff the first did, it was a complete answer, and was most helpful for you. There is a reason why multiple answers can be submitted to a single question.

“Builder Scrolls”? Also, the “tea drinking, British” was spot on. Exploiter… well. I sometimes abuse things in grindy games, but I’ll always go through the whole fight. The devs built it, so I might as well respect their effort. And it’s fun to beat hard games. Also… sanity?! Never heard of it (lol). Good answer though.

@Daemons & Dragonrage - I like how both our answers ironically answer different facets of the question. ;)

@Daemons, Builder Scrolls is an alternate universe version of Elder Scrolls, in which they released new games instead of just re-releasing the 5th game 20 times. The tea drinking, British exploiter was a reference to The Spiffing Brit, a YouTuber who loves playing games exactly as the developers intended (if the bug/glitch/exploit is in the game, clearly the developer wanted you to use it).

@Dragonrage I thought that was a reference, but I couldn’t quite be sure.

An accepted answer is just the answer that worked best for you, the question asker. It isn't a locked in choice, you can change answer acceptance at any time with no penalty to yourself*.
If both answers are adequate, you could pick one at random. If neither are adequate, then leaving comments asking for further clarification would be appropriate. You could also simply choose to not accept an answer. That's also... acceptable. :)
* the original accepted answer OP will lose the bonus 15 rep for having their answer accepted. Also, if you unaccept without accepting another answer, you lose the 2 rep for accepting an answer.

I was about to post a comment asking why you italicised the “acceptable”, but then I got the joke (lol). I suppose I’ll just accept the answer with the most useful info. Going to wait to accept this until it’s been a bit longer/answer gets more upvotes.

The word “accept feels inordinately odd now…

Haha yeah. Some words are weird like that
